# Mock final method in superclass

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am creating a new service 'MyService' that extends [AbstractScheduledService](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractScheduledService.html) and MyService inherits a final method *isRunning()* from it.

```
public class MyService extends AbstractScheduledService {}
```

I also have a health check for 'MyService' that invokes *isRunning()* to see if 'MyService' is healthy.

```
public class MyServiceHealthcheck {
       MyService myService;
       
       @Inject
       public MyServiceHealthCheck(MyService myService) {
          this.myService = myService;
       }

       public boolean isHealthy() {
          return myService.isRunning();
       }
}
```

And finally, I am trying to create unit test 'MyServiceHealthcheckTest' for testing MyServiceHealthcheck

```
public class MyServiceHealthcheckTest {
       @Mock MyService myService;
}
```

The mock is initialized properly and I'm able to get expected value for methods defined in MyService but *myService.isRunning()* always returns a NullPointerException. What is the best way to mock *isRunning()* method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Mockito so that mocking final classes and methods is possible. To achieve this you need to add a text file named `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` to your project `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions` directory. It should include a single line of text as follows: `mock-maker-inline`.